# Efficient way of having synchronous and asynchronous behavior in an application

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to make `synchronous` and `asynchronous` behavior of my client. In general, how our client will work as below -

Customer will call our client with a `userId` and we will construct a URL from that `userId` and make a HTTP call to that URL and we will get a JSON String back after hitting the URL. And after we get the response back as a JSON String, then we will send that JSON String back to our customer.

So in this case, as I mentioned above, I need to have `synchronous` and `asynchronous` methods, some customer will call `executeSynchronous` method to get the same feature and some customer will call our `executeAsynchronous` method to get the data back.

Below is my Interface -

```
public interface Client {

    // for synchronous
    public String executeSynchronous(final String userId);

    // for asynchronous
    public Future<String> executeAsynchronous(final String userId);
}
```

And then I have our `SmartClient` which implements the above `Client` interface.

```
public class SmartClient implements Client {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    // This is for synchronous call
    @Override
    public String execute(String userId) {

        String response = null;
        Future<String> handle = getHandle(userId);

        try {
            response = handle.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        }

        return response;
    }

    // This is for asynchronous call
    @Override
    public Future<String> executeAsync(String userId) {

        return getHandle(userId);

    }

    private Future<String> getHandle(String userId) {
        Future<String> future = null;

        Task task = new Task(userId);
        future = executor.submit(task);

        return future;

    }
}
```

Below is my simple class which will perform the actual task -

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private final String userId;

    public Task(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;   
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = createURL(userId);

        // make a HTTP call to the URL
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String jsonResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    // create a URL
    private String createURL(String userId) {
        String generateURL = somecode;

        return generateURL;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct and efficient way of doing this problem? And how about exception handling? Do I need any other catch blocks at any places? If any, then just a high level code example will help me understand to better.

If there is any better way, then please let me know... I am still learning..

Answer (score 1):

I would implement **executeSynchronous** this way:

```
 public String execute(String userId){
    Task task = new Task(userID);
    return task.call();      //Task executes in the caller thread
 }
```

I would not use execution framework since call shall execute in the caller thread. Bu think you meant to provide a timeout mechanism in the synchronous method so that caller does not get blocked. If not I think there is no need to use execution framework in the synchronous method.